# Running JavaScript after using WooCommerce Filter Plugin

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, ajax, javascript, jquery

I’m using the Product Filters Plugin for [filter products](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-filters/?quid=9d77ffbd959c82e44f77e745bd9971ee) on my WooCommerce Store. I wan’t to do a complex design for the filter menu with JavaScript/jQuery but once I click on one of the filter’s inputs the JavaScript won’t run again.
I researched the problem and from what I understand the problem is with running JS after AJAX. I didn’t find a solution though.
Do someone here knows what what do in this situation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all you need to do is run JS after an ajax request check [jQuery .ajaxComplete()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Thanks for the reply. I tried to do that. Doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Consider adding the code that you tried to apply to your question, that will help us narrow down the problem. Edit your question to contain the JS code.